# Regular expression find and replace

Tags: regular-expression

Trying to use regex

`25, s/\(Test.assert_equals(\)\(pick_peaks([.*\])\)\(.*\)/print("\2")/g`

to replace the lines below with print(pick_peaks(...))

My find pattern seems to be working as in vim the text all highlights until I enter the / to input the substitution text. Then when I do final /g and enter it gives the pattern not found error.

```
Test.assert_equals(pick_peaks([1,2,3,6,4,1,2,3,2,1]), {"pos":[3,7], "peaks":[6,3]})
Test.assert_equals(pick_peaks([3,2,3,6,4,1,2,3,2,1,2,3]), {"pos":[3,7], "peaks":[6,3]})
Test.assert_equals(pick_peaks([3,2,3,6,4,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,1]), {"pos":[3,7,10], "peaks":[6,3,2]})
Test.assert_equals(pick_peaks([2,1,3,1,2,2,2,2,1]), {"pos":[2,4], "peaks":[3,2]})
Test.assert_equals(pick_peaks([2,1,3,1,2,2,2,2]), {"pos":[2], "peaks":[3]})
Test.assert_equals(pick_peaks([2,1,3,2,2,2,2,5,6]), {"pos":[2], "peaks":[3]})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We really need a complete example of what is your expected result, otherwise we have to guess what you want and it will be hard to help you. Does something like this work for you `%s/.*\(pick_peaks([[0-9,]\+])\).*/print(\1)`?

Comment: Yeah that works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your command can be simplified a lot:

- You don't need a capture group around `Test.assert_equals(` and you can simply match it with `.*` since you already match the interesting string `pick_peaks...`
- You can be more restrictive on the pattern of what the parenthesis contain after `pick_peak(`: you don't want to match `.*` but only digits and commas.
- You don't need a capture group for everything after the interesting string.

So your solution could look like this:

```
:%s/.*\(pick_peaks([[0-9,]\+])\).*/print(\1)
```

With details on the pattern:

```
.*\(pick_peaks([[0-9,]\+])\).*
.*                              All the characters before the string you want to match
  \(                      \)    Let's capture only what we want to reuse
    pick_peaks([        ])      These are all plain characters
                [0-9,]\+        The brackets above can contain one or more (\+) digits (0-9) or commas (,)
```